# Can I use an absolute path from windows for an application installed on WSL ubuntu?

Tags: interop, absolute-path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed an application called NWChem on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux. I can access it directly from the Windows 10 command line using the built in WSL interoperability application wsl.exe by just entering 'wsl nwchem'. However I am trying to install a GUI front end called MoCalc2012 that requires absolute paths for the applications that it uses. If instead of entering an absolute path I put the command 'wsl nwchem' it produces the unhandled exception warning that: 'Path cannot be the empty string or white space'.

[image]

Instead of using 'wsl nwchem' is there a method within WSL interoperability to define a absolute path that will stop MoCalc2012 trying to close down because of an unhandled exception?

The path in Ubuntu is '/usr/bin/nwchem'.

I tried to solve this by making a symbolic link as follows:

mklink C:\Program Files\NWChem\nwchem.exe 'wsl nwchem'

but this gave a syntax error, as did putting /J in the command.

Comment: @Biswappriyo I think it would take you an enormous amount of effort to reproduce my issue because paths are needed for MOPAC, GAMESS, Firefly, NWChem, ORCA before it will stop protesting. Most of these programs require academic registration before a key can be obtained. If you really want to have a go the Mocalc manual with installation instructions for all the additional 5 programs plus the Mocalc download can be found at http://www.profanderson.net/files/mocalc.php at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Try with double quote in path.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks for your suggestion, I have tried various combinations "wsl nwchem", 'wsl nwchem', wsl"nwchem", C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe nwchem,C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe"nwchem" but haven't found a combination that prevents the Unhandled exception. Since I get the unhandled exception whether the five boxes are all filled in or not there is not way of being sure exactly what is calling the failure.I may have to see if I can dip into the code to see if I can apply the test box by box to see if the other boxes pass the test.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of MoCalc2012. This does not work because it was never meant to work with WSL. You need to install NWChem to the Windows side of your system.

Comment: I understand that MoCalc2012 came before WSL and was therefore not designed to work with it. But it seemed worth trying to see if there was a possible work around to avoid yet another emulation layer on one of my computers. I think Microsoft should be applauded and encouraged for the efforts they have made with WSL especially the strides they have made with interoperability. A work around seemed a possibility when I found that NWChem was easily accessible from the command line in windows with wsl nwchem. However as nobody else seems to be interested I will install MinGW and get on with it.